# How to make a 90 degrees circle

Tags: javascript, geometry, automatic-ref-counting, degrees

So i have done processingjs in 1 year now and I thought I would start with pure javascript now in lockdown, I have been coding Javascript for 2 months now and I've done many remixes of old arcade games.

But yesterday I was very bored and I was like heyy, I could make a like loading screen.
So i did, i made 3 canvases one was at the top of the screen and there was a rectangle that went from left to right and whenever the rectangle dissapeared from the screen i would take it back so that it started on the left side again, that code looked like this

```
        const c = document.getElementById("loadingRect");
        const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var x = 10;
        function drawSomething() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(x, 5, 100, 5);
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
            drawSomething();
            x+=10;
            if(x>c.width) {
                x=-100
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }
        draw();
```

Then I made another script (just for me to be easier to write code).
Where I did like a loading text that were in the 90s games, like Loading -> Loading. -> Loading.. -> Loading... -> and over again. I know that there's problaby a more efficient way for me to do this but yeah.

```
        const canvas = document.getElementById("loadingText");
        const ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var time = 0;
        function loadingText() {
            ctx2.font = "30px Arial";
            ctx2.fillText("Loading", 140, 210);
        }
        function dot1() {
            ctx2.font = "30px Arial";
            ctx2.fillText(".", 245, 210);
        }
        function dot2() {
            ctx2.font = "30px Arial";
            ctx2.fillText(".", 250, 210);
        }
        function dot3() {
            ctx2.font = "30px Arial";
            ctx2.fillText(".", 255, 210);
        }
        function draw2() {
            ctx2.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            loadingText();
            if(time >= 60) {
                dot1();
            }
            if(time >= 120) {
                dot2();
            }
            if(time >= 180) {
                dot3();
            }
            if(time >= 240) {
                time = 0;
            }
            // I could use here time++; i know
            time += 1;
            requestAnimationFrame(draw2); 
        }
        draw2();
```

Keep  in mind that was two different canvases. And then this day i had this really cool thing i wanted to make like the Microsoft logging in screen, circle. My idea was not to make a cool transition but more like my loading text where I make a 4, 90 Degrees circles but they have to be like start at the top and end at the right, start at the right and end at the bottom, I hope you understand so i tried this.

```
        const canv = document.getElementById("loadingCircle");
        const ctx3 = canv.getContext("2d");

        function loadingCircle1() {
            ctx3.beginPath();
            ctx3.arc(200, 200, 75, 0, Math.PI/2);
            ctx3.stroke();
            ctx3.closePath();
        }
        // This was my other try
        function loadingCircle2() {
            ctx3.beginPath();
            ctx3.arc(200, 200, 75, 90, Math.PI/2);
            ctx3.stroke();
            ctx3.closePath();
        }
        // Test for now to see if they are 90 degrees
        loadingCircle1();
        loadingCircle2();
```

But that didn't work because the circle would not start at the top, the bottom, the left.
There my plan was ruined and I tried different values in half an hour but it just didn't work, so I went here and asked for help.

I'm not saying I request for code or something i **just want to know the values of the last two parameters in the circle 3 more times so that together they build a perfectly round and nice circle.

(excuse me for my bad English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a simple answer, your desired values in radians are:

```
Top: -(Math.PI / 2)
Right: 0
Bottom: Math.PI / 2
Left: Math.PI
```

Comment: If this helped you, could you please accept the answer and give it an upvote? Thanks!

Comment: I have under 15 repulation, so i can't

Comment: Really? Have you tried? You should at least be able to set it as correct solution. I think you should also be able to upvote, maybe you can't see it though ..?